# In admin panel dropdown's are not working

Tags: magento-1.8

**Mag v1.8.1.0**

I tried opening `system>transational emails>New` but nothing is shown in the drop down.

When i did inspect element the following error is displayed.

```
<select id="template_select" name="code" class="select required-entry">
Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_CsVendorVacation_Helper_Data' not found in /home/rootname/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is or there was a module called CsVendorVacation on your website and either its helper is not declared properly or the helper does not exist anymore but is still getting called in your code.

As you can see, as Magento can't find the helper, it automatically fallbacks to Mage and tries to locate it as a Mage module but it is definitely not a Mage module.

If the module is still installed, ensure the helper is declared properly.
If you don't have that module anymore, look for 'CsVendorVacation' and 'csvendorvacation' in your files and locate the call to the helper that is causing problem.